# Need Help Reading the TensorBoard Profiler Tea Leaves : TensorFlow data.Dataset.prefetch with AUTOTUNE Running Synchronously

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to figure out how to improve the data pipeline performance for a CNN model that I am running on Google Cloud with the dataset stored in Google Cloud Storage. The image dataset is too large to cache in memory.

I used the commonly cited Data Pipeline tutorials to implement my Data Pipeline using data.Dataset.map, and the period of data fetching and preprocessing to actual GPU computation was about 2:1 or 3-4 seconds per step (i.e., the GPU sat idle for 2 seconds for every 1 second in ran).

In an attempt to improve this I incorporated data.Dataset.interleave, but both the data prep to processing time ratio and seconds per step have both remained the same.

In order to understand where the bottleneck is, I implemented a TensorBoard profiler callback, and the profile of the GPU computes and the prefetch processes on the CPU appear to be synchronous. I utilized data.Dataset.AUTOTUNE, but still it seems like the GPU is waiting for the CPU to complete the prefetch before making the pass through the model. I monitored CPU usage in htop during the run, and it doesn't appear to be maxed out. Does anyone have any ideas about how to remedy this?

The main tutorials I've looked at are:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler

https://cs230.stanford.edu/blog/datapipeline

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnukSLKEw34&ab_channel=TensorFlow

Here are my environment settings:

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
os.environ['TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR'] = "cuda_malloc_async"
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```

Here is the code for my data pipeline:

```
def get_label(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
    one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
    return tf.argmax(one_hot)

def decode_img(img):
    img = tf.io.decode_image(img, channels=3, expand_animations = False)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [244, 244])
    img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)
    return img

def process_path(file_path):
    label = get_label(file_path)
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    return img, label

def configure_for_performance(ds):
    ds = ds.batch(128)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    return ds
```

```
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files((data_dir + '/*/*.png'), shuffle=False)
files = files.shuffle(image_count, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

val_size = int(image_count * 0.2)

train_files = files.skip(val_size)
val_files = files.take(val_size)

train_ds = train_files.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([x]), cycle_length=4, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

val_ds = val_files.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([x]), cycle_length=4, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

train_ds = configure_for_performance(train_ds)
val_ds = configure_for_performance(val_ds)
```

Based on the TensorFlow data pipeline tutorial video linked above, here is how I expect the processed to run (the second example in this image)

[image: synchronous and asynchronous data pipeline processing]

Here is the TensorBoard profile output of my model's CPU processes during training with lots of asynchronous interleaving stuff going on:

[image]

But the last line in the above CPU processing image, which is the prefetch process, is synchronous with the GPU processing, similar to the unoptimized example in the first image:

[image]

Comment: have you found solution? I can't get simplest dataset (generating just `np.zeros(100), 1`) to work fast as it should be..